# show a div of image only in homepage and hide from other pages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, model-view-controller

```
<div class="container">
    
                        @section HeroSection{
                            @foreach (var category in Model.AllCategory.Where(m => m.IsFeatured).FirstOrDefault().CategoryPictures.Select(m => m.Picture).Distinct())
                            {
                                <div class="hero__item set-bg" data-setbg="/FileStore/images/@category.Url">
                                    <div class="hero__text">
                                        <span>FRUIT FRESH</span>
                                        <h2>Vegetable <br />100% Organic</h2>
                                        <p>Free Pickup and Delivery Available</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="primary-btn">SHOP NOW</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                           }
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        }
</div>
```

I tried to @Render the //@section HeroSection// as false in _layout page .so that it will only appear in home/index ..not in other pages!

Comment: Why not just add this code to your homepage view?

Comment: actually it is appearing after the header div with a dropdown and a search box and also with the #div of image .. as i am using the only one _layout ..the image div appearing in all view .. i just want to keep the  image div in homepage only. and other parts as dropdown list and search box will be global in _layout..   Tnx in advance !

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend to achieve, but you can set a boolean variable in the method of the controller that you want to show this image on its view and then show or hide base on that boolean variable in the view

Comment: https://colorlib.com/wp/template/ogani/     . as on this template a (Vegetable 100% organic) image banner is used  only ! in homepage but  in that same section dropdown list and searching div will be global in layout . I am trying to fix this !

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 approaches.
the first one is not so practical which is making 2 different layouts, one without the div and one with it. And you can change the layout of the homepage in the razor file like this

```
@{Layout = "YourNewLayOut"}
```

The other approach which I think it's better is to use JavaScript.
you can use `window.location.href` to get the current url and check if it's the url of the home page you target the div and make hidden otherwise visible.

your function should look like this :

```
function someFunctionName() {
  let div = document.querySelector("#yourDiv");
  if (window.location.href === "your home page url ") {
    div.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    div.style.display = "block or flex or what ever you're using";
  }
}
```

and then Invoke this function on loading like this

```
window.onload = function() {
someFunctionName();
};
```